# Authorization header is missing in request from client via Azure AD Application Proxy

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-function-app-proxy

I am facing an issue with missing Authorization header with Bearer token in the HTTP request from the client application to REST web service via Azure Active Directory Application Proxy.

The web service is hosted in on-premises and client application is consuming from internet using Azure AD application proxy URL and the request is authenticated against ADFS. The authentication header is added upon sending request to Azure AD application proxy URL and I guess it was removed by the proxy connector.

Please find the request content below and help. How can I include Authenticator header in the original request to Application proxy?

```
GET /TimelogSvc/rest/Timelog/GetTimeLog?EmailId=John@BizNext.com.sg&Fromdate=2019-04-21&Todate=2019-04-27 HTTP/1.1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: agileuat.BizNext.com.sg
X-Forwarded-For: 203.126.130.140
X-MS-Proxy: AzureAD-Application-Proxy
OS-Host: agileuat.BizNext.com.sg
OS-Path: /TimelogSvc
OS-Pta: /rest/Timelog
OS-Page: /GetTimeLog?EmailId=John08@BizNext.com.sg&Fromdate=2019-04-21&Todate=2019-04-27
```

Please also see my code below of the client.

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority + tenantID);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
string s = string.Empty;

result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, new Uri(redirectUri), new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto));

// Append the token as bearer in the request header.
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);

// Call the API.
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://timelogapitest-BizNext.msappproxy.net/TimelogSvc/rest/Timelog/GetTimeLog?EmailId=John@bizNext.com.sg&Fromdate=2019-04-21&Todate=2019-04-27");

s = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Mobile applications**

I've worked around this by including the access token in a custom header (a second time). This assumes you have control over the backend so you can read that custom header. If necessary, you could even write this into the AuthHeader on the backend to ensure normal authorization flow from there.

```
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "API/URL/GoesHere");
            // Add token to authentication header as per usual
            message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            // Custom header containing the token a second time.
            // Name if whatever you like, just make sure you look for the
            // exact name on the backend
            message.Headers.Add("JwtAccessToken", token);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

**Web Clients**

This seems to work now:

[https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32386468-forward-incoming-jwt-token-to-backend-service#{toggle_previous_statuses}](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32386468-forward-incoming-jwt-token-to-backend-service#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)